# Struggling with saving a response file as pdf and attaching it directly to an item fulfillment

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am currently on a project for work, in which I worked with a team from our logistics company to integrate our freight services. The way the workflow is currently ***(this is a user event script by the way)***, is that the information needed for the shipment is gathered in a custom tab during the item fulfillment. We have a Suitelet that acts as a quote picker, so when the 'Get Quote' button we created is clicked, we get a price sheet with rates for various carriers.
The data is not sent to their system until the submit takes place, and when this happens we transform the relevant data into a bill of lading, which is the returned object.
Currently, we have the returned pdf set to save to a specific folder in the file cabinet, but the file is not directly associated with the transaction record.
I am trying to use the 'mediaitem' field to directly attach the pdf to the record via the files subtab inside of the communication tab. I have tried setting the attachments received folder as the destination instead of the custom 'Freight BOL' we have created in the file cabinet, but this does not attach it to the actual record.
Below is a snippet of our import code ***(I have altered it to avoid sharing the exact code)*** that currently saves the 'BOL' pdf file to our file cabinet:

```
        ***//above this is the post containing API key and etc***
        if (response.code != 200) {
        var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
        log.error ({
            title: 'order #' + sonum + ' shipment import: ' + response.code,
            details: responseBody.Message
        });
        log.error ({
            title: 'order #' + sonum + ' shipment import messageBody',
            details: JSON.stringify(messageBody)
        });
        return;
    }
    //save BOL to Freight BOL folder in File Cabinet
    var bolFile = saveBOL(response);
    var fileId = bolFile.save();


  } catch (e) {
    log.error ({
      title: 'order #' + sonum + ' error: ' + e.name,
      details: e.message
    });
    log.error ({
      title: 'order #' + sonum + ' DLS Import messageBody',
      details: messageBody
    });
  }
}

function saveBOL(response){
  var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    var bolFile = file.create({
      name: responseBody.FileName,
      fileType: file.Type.PDF,
      contents: responseBody.FileBytes,
      folder: //folderidishere,
      isOnline: false
    });

  var fileId = bolFile.save();
  return bolFile;

}
```

I am struggling to find anything via documentation or SuiteAnswers regarding saving a file as an attachment to an order via SuiteScript 2.0. Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the attach method of the N/record module.

```
    var id = record.attach({
    record: {
        type: 'file',
        id: bolFile
    },
    to: {
        type: 'itemfulfillment',
        id: <internalid of item fulfillment>
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have one question regarding this, is there a best way to encapsulate the id of the item fulfillment as it is being created? I am actually a C# developer, and this is my first actual experience working with JavaScript. Any suggestions on good learning material, or just tips in general would be much appreciated!